# how can I remove Models from a list by the index in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, listtile

So I have a List with some Models in it

```dart
List<add_ingridients_list> added_ingridients_list = [
  add_ingridients_list("a", "b", "c"),
  add_ingridients_list("a", "b", "c"),
  add_ingridients_list("a", "b", "c")
];
```

and now i want to create a function where i can delete specific models in this list by the index

i came up with a function looking like this

```dart
delete_ingredient_from_meal(int i, added_ingridients_list) {
  // i is the index of the ListModel i want to delete
  added_ingridients_list = added_ingridients_list.remove(i);
  return added_ingridients_list;
}
```

but it isnt working, can someone give me an small example how this function should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an item from a list based on the item's index, use [removeAt](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeAt.html) instead of [remove](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/remove.html).

From the [List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html) docs:

> `dart bool remove( Object? value )`
>
> [[remove](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/remove.html)] removes the first occurrence of value from this list.
>
> `dart E removeAt( int index )`
>
> [[removeAt](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/removeAt.html)] removes the object at position index from this list.

## Solution:

Change:

```dart
added_ingridients_list = added_ingridients_list.remove(i);
```

to:

```dart
added_ingridients_list.removeAt(i);
```

### Note:

- `removeAt` mutates the list and so you don't need to reassign the `added_ingridients_list` variable.
- `removeAt` returns the removed value. To get the removed value, do this:

  ```dart
  final removedItem = added_ingridients_list.remove(i);
  ```